# C# tooltip : need cursor visibility set to false

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to get the cursor visibility set to false when the tooltip is visible and back to true again when the tooltip disappears?

Comment: yes its possible, just set the cursor to none when the tootip opens and and set it back when it closes

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Make that an answer? :)

Comment: Making it difficult for the user to dismiss the tooltip is just hostile.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

As sa_ddam213 said:

Simply use the [Cursors.None Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.input.cursors.none.aspx)

---

Or you could do this manually by setting a transparent Cursor image before the `ToolTip.Show()` and after the `ToolTip.Hide()` simply show the normal Cursor:

```
CursorHandler.LoadCursor("ProjName.Resources.Invisible.cur");
ToolTip.Show();
```

...

```
ToolTip.Hide();
CursorHandler.LoadCursor("ProjName.Resources.Normal.cur");
```

Here is the CursorHandler code (that I got from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36540/Adobe-Eyedropper-Control):

```
public class CursorHandler
{
 [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
 private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);

public static Cursor LoadCursor(string resourcePath)
{
    Cursor c = new Cursor(getCursorHandle(resourcePath));
    return c;
}    

private static IntPtr getCursorHandle(string resourcePath)
{
    //Load cursor from Manifest Resource to Stream 
    Stream streamFrom =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
    Stream streamTo =
    File.Create(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\~cur.tmp");
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(streamFrom);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(streamTo);
    //Write cursor to temporary file 
    bw.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)streamFrom.Length));
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
    br.Close();
    bw = null;
    br = null;
    streamFrom.Close();
    streamTo.Close();
    streamFrom = null;
    streamTo = null;
    //Load handle of temporary cursor file 
    IntPtr hwdCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\~cur.tmp");
    //Delete temporary cursor file 
    File.Delete(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\~cur.tmp");
    return hwdCursor;
}
```

Comment: Very hard to believe that this does anything like hiding the cursor.  Tooltip windows control the cursor themselves, you can't get to their message handler easily.  Especially notable is that the return value of LoadCursor() isn't used at all.  Did you actually test it?